# App using new version of Realm can't open DB created with app using older version of Realm

Tags: ios, realm

I have an app in the App Store which was using Realm and RealmSwift version 4.4.0.

I've updated the version of these to 5.0.2 in a new version of the app, but if the app is installed over the top of the App Store version there is the following error:

> "Underlying=Database has an unsupported version and cannot be
>   upgraded"

If Realm 5.0.2 isn't backwards compatible with Realm 4.4.0 then I'll have to roll back to v4.4.0.
But surely surely surely this cannot be the case, surely no way they wouldn't make it backwards compatible. So therefore how can I use Realm 5 with a Realm 4 created DB?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to programmatically upgrade a read-only Realm database in my iOS app. I can't open it in Realm Studio.

Comment: @clifton Labrum, no eventually I just rolled back to the old realm

Comment: I since learned about this simple trick to get past this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781014/how-to-programmatically-upgrade-read-only-realm-file-to-latest-version-in-ios-ap

Answer (score 0):

Databases updated to 5.0.x are not backward compatible. e.g. If a Realm is upgraded for 5, it must be used with API's that support 5 and above.

From the change log (Realm Studio):

> When opening a file which is using an older format, you will get
>   prompted to upgrade (and optionally backup) the Realm file. NOTE: Once
>   the file has been upgraded, there is no way to downgrade it again and
>   it can only be used by the SDKs that support Realm file format v10.

Comment: Who gets prompted? This is for an iOS Realm database created on an iPhone, then attempting to be updated by an app using Realm v5. There is no prompting occurring, nor opportunity for the app to perform the upgrade. This this the problem - the database does not even get the chance to get upgraded to 5 because it can't be opened.

Comment: @Gruntcakes Perhaps I misunderstood. From the [Realm 5.0.0 Release notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v5.0.0) which states *NOTE: This version bumps the Realm file format to version 10. It is not possible to downgrade version 9 or earlier. Files created with older versions of Realm will be automatically upgraded*. Not saying I am happy about that either and we had several Realm upgraded and could no longer open them with RealmStudio (11 works) - there may have been better ways to roll that out but it's there in the release notes. Perhaps that's not what you're describing?

Comment: Oh, and this *Files containing Any properties can no longer be opened. This property type was never documented and was deprecated in 1.0.*

Comment: Seems my Realm DB isn't getting automatically upgraded, I don't think I'm using Any but will check. Ta

Comment: @aehlke There isn't really a resolution as it's not really an issue. If you upgrade to Realm 5.0.x it cannot be downgraded and must be used with 5.0.x API's and Realm Studio 11.0. Likewise if you open an older Realm with Real Studio 11.0, it will update that Realm. Do you have a question about that process? If so, post it and we'll take a look.