# How to Programmatically Upgrade Read-only Realm File to Latest Version in iOS App

Tags: realm

I recently updated Realm in my iOS app to `10.1.2`. But then I got a crash that says:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: ... "The Realm file format must be allowed to be upgraded in order to proceed." ... Realm file needs upgrade before opening in RO mode Path: ...

This `remote.realm` file is a user's data they have stored on a remote server that gets downloaded to the iOS app and used for various things. But that remote file is on `3.x` while my iOS app is now using `10.x`.

I know that opening a Realm in Realm Studio can perform an upgrade, but how do I upgrade/open a read-only Realm file from within my Cocoa app and convert it to the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're downloading the file and not re-uploading it somewhere or sharing it between processes, you could catch the error, open it without the readonly flag to perform the upgrade, then re-open it as readonly and return to the caller. I'm not super familiar with the swift API, but in pseudocode, it would look like:

```
func openRealm(config: Realm.Configuration) -> Realm {
    do {
         return try Realm(config)
    }
    catch migrationException {
        config.readOnly = false
        try! Realm(config)
        config.readOnly = true
        return try! Realm(config)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the suggestion I got here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6928 Removing the `readOnly` flag was all I needed to do in order for the remote realm to open and upgrade properly. 

Comment: Ugh! Now I feel bad for stealing Thomas's points 